# How to fuse a specific type of nodes in XML data in R?

Tags: xml, r, merge, cpu-word, paragraph

I have an XML file of a book. The main tree has *Body/Pagecolumn/Region/Paragraph/Line/Word* levels. However, I am not interested in the *Line* level. Is there any way to fuse the *Line* level without destroying the *Word* level in R using XML package or any other package? After the conversion, the main tree would be *Body/Pagecolumn/Region/Paragraph/Word*

A sample of the XML data is provided below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DjVuXML>
<DjVuXML>
<BODY>
<OBJECT data="file://localhost//book1.djvu" height="1650" type="image/x.djvu" usemap="book1.djvu" width="1275">
<PARAM name="PAGE" value="book1_001.djvu"/>
<PARAM name="DPI" value="300"/>
<HIDDENTEXT>
<PAGECOLUMN>
<REGION>
<PARAGRAPH>
<LINE>
<WORD coords="1,2,3,4,5">Title</WORD>
</LINE>
</PARAGRAPH>
</REGION>
</PAGECOLUMN>
<PAGECOLUMN>
<REGION>
<PARAGRAPH>
<LINE>
<WORD coords="30,564,90,545,559">This</WORD>
<WORD coords="97,559,109,545,559">is</WORD>
<WORD coords="115,564,162,545,559">a</WORD>
</LINE>
</PARAGRAPH>
<PARAGRAPH>
<LINE>
<WORD coords="30,589,80,570,584">First</WORD>
<WORD coords="88,584,115,570,584">line</WORD>
<WORD coords="123,584,146,574,584">is</WORD>
</LINE>
<LINE>
<WORD coords="30,614,90,598,609">Second</WORD>
<WORD coords="97,609,143,595,609">line</WORD>
<WORD coords="148,614,168,595,609">is</WORD>
</LINE>
<LINE>
<WORD coords="30,640,56,626,640">Third</WORD>
<WORD coords="63,640,95,626,640">line</WORD>
<WORD coords="101,640,128,626,640">is</WORD>
</LINE>
</PARAGRAPH>
</REGION>
</PAGECOLUMN>
</HIDDENTEXT>
</OBJECT>
<MAP name="book1.djvu"/>
</BODY>
</DjVuXML>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the easy regexp solutions and in this case they are probably the way to go. In general with `XML` we would look to use `XSLT`. This is a language for transforming `XML`. There is an R package `Sxslt` which can be used to transform `XML`. The idea is to define 2 templates:

1. The first template is whats known as the identity transform . This copies all attributes and nodes. If there is a more relevant template for a particular element xslt will use that instead.
2. Then We declared a template more relevant to LINE. This does nothing. So for all nodes and attributes except LINE the transform performs a copy.

Here mye code:

```
# install package if needed
# install.packages('Sxslt', repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
require(Sxslt)
# define a transformation
sltTemp <- '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LINE">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>'

# assume your XML is text variable named xdata
# you can also work on a parsed file if you like
# xD <- xmlParse(xdata)
# xsltApplyStyleSheet(xD, sltTemp)
# gives same result

require(XML)
newxdata <- saveXML(xsltApplyStyleSheet(xdata, sltTemp))
xmlParse(newxdata)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DjVuXML>
  <BODY>
    <OBJECT data="file://localhost//book1.djvu" height="1650" type="image/x.djvu" usemap="book1.djvu" width="1275">
      <PARAM name="PAGE" value="book1_001.djvu"/>
      <PARAM name="DPI" value="300"/>
      <HIDDENTEXT>
        <PAGECOLUMN>
          <REGION>
            <PARAGRAPH>
              <WORD coords="1,2,3,4,5">Title</WORD>
            </PARAGRAPH>
          </REGION>
        </PAGECOLUMN>
        <PAGECOLUMN>
          <REGION>
            <PARAGRAPH>
              <WORD coords="30,290,65,276,290">This</WORD>
              <WORD coords="73,290,84,276,290">is</WORD>
              <WORD coords="92,290,100,280,290">a</WORD>
            </PARAGRAPH>
            <PARAGRAPH>
              <WORD coords="30,290,65,276,290">First</WORD>
              <WORD coords="73,290,84,276,290">line</WORD>
              <WORD coords="92,290,100,280,290">is</WORD>
              <WORD coords="30,290,65,276,290">Second</WORD>
              <WORD coords="73,290,84,276,290">line</WORD>
              <WORD coords="92,290,100,280,290">is</WORD>
              <WORD coords="30,290,65,276,290">Third</WORD>
              <WORD coords="73,290,84,276,290">line</WORD>
              <WORD coords="92,290,100,280,290">is</WORD>
            </PARAGRAPH>
          </REGION>
        </PAGECOLUMN>
      </HIDDENTEXT>
    </OBJECT>
    <MAP name="book1.djvu"/>
  </BODY>
</DjVuXML>
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks great! a couple of questions, I can't install it for windows , do I need to compile it from source?  If I understand your code , in this case , does the code still work with this transformation `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`, I mean without the @*?

Comment: Unfortunatley I dont think a windows version is available. The first template is whats known as the identity transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform . This copies all attributes and nodes. If there is a more relevant template for a particular element xslt will use that instead. We declared a template more relevant to LINE. This does nothing. So for all nodes and attributes except LINE the transform performs a copy. The result is the original XML minus the LINE parts.

Comment: Thanks. I am also using R on windows. I tried to install from the source using RStudio, but I got this error: *Please define LIB_XSLT*.

Comment: I tried it on a Linux system, and it worked like a charm! I hope to see a work around for windows installation.

Comment: @user1609452 I just edit to add your excellent explanation in the comment.

Comment: Yes I tried to get it working on my windows machine. There are windows binaries at http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html for the various components. It probably just requires the make file to point at them but I couldnt get it going.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use the `xml` package and do the nodes fusing.

However, for the sample xml that you have provided, you might be able to get away with a simple `gsub` (find and replace).

Something along the lines of:

```
xmlfile <- readLines("test.xml")
newfile <- gsub("<LINE>|</LINE>", "", xmlfile)
```

And go from there.

Comment: Thanks. However, I will wait a little more to see if a modular solution also comes up.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution using `grepl` to remove all lines:

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
ll <- ll[!grepl("<LINE>|</LINE>" ,ll)]
txt <- paste(ll, "\n", collapse="")
xmlParse(txt,asText=TRUE)
```